# A question concerning isometries and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $e_1 = (1, 0)$ and $e_2 = (0, 1)$. Assume that $f : \Bbb R^2 → \Bbb R^2$ is an isometry of the plane fixing $(0, 0)$.
>   Let $f(e_1) = (a, b)$ and $f(e_2) = (c, d)$, and let $A = \begin{vmatrix}
> a & c \\
> b & d \\
> \end{vmatrix}$. Prove that $\det A=±1$.

So far from what I can gather, since $f$ is an isometry, it preserves distances. So we have that $d(f(e_1), f(e_2)) = d(e_1, e_2)$.

So we have that $\sqrt{(a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2} = \sqrt{2}$. Unfortunately this leaves a number of possibilities. In any sense $(a-c), (b-d) = 1$, I think. I'm a little lost on where to go from here showing that, $ad-bc = \pm 1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use the fact that $\det A$ is equal to the (signed) area of the parallelogram defined by its columns.

Answer (score 2):

An isometry fixing the origin is a linear orthogonal map. So $A$ is an orthogonal matrix satisfying $AA^T=I$, This implies $\det(A)^2=1$, or $\det(A)=\pm 1$.