# Norm preserving linear transformation preserves volumes

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

If $T:\mathbf R^n\to\mathbf R^n$ is a norm preserving linear transformation and $M$ is a $k$-manifold in $\mathbf R^n$, show that $M$ has the same volume as $T(M)$.

This is an exercise from Spivak. The volume is defined as follows:

> Let $M$ be a $k$-dimensional manifold (or manifold-with-boundary) in $\mathbf{R}^n$, with an orientation $\mu$. If $x\in M$, then $\mu_x$ and the inner product $T_x$ we defined previously determine a volume element $\omega(x)\in\Lambda^k(M_x)$. We therefore obtain a nowhere-zero $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$, which is called the **volume element** on $M$ (determined by $\mu$) and denoted $dV$, even though it is not generally the differential of a $(k-1)$-form. The **volume** of $M$ is defined as $\int_M dV$, provided this integral exists, which is certainly the case if $M$ is compact. "Volume" is usually called **length** or **surface area** for one- and two-dimensional manifolds, and $dV$ is denoted $ds$ (the "element of length") or $dA$ [or $dS$] (the "element of [surface] area").

I don't know how to approach the problem. It looks like I need to find $\omega$, then take $T$ of the corresponding integral, etc. But I don't know how to do any of the steps from these strategy...

Comment: Have you considered using the change of variables formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables)? Since $T$ is norm-preserving, you can see that $|det(T)| = 1$ (as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645056/a-question-concerning-isometries-and-determinants).

Comment: @AnCoileanach: You're working in $n$-dimensions with that comment, not on a $k$-dimensional submanifold.

Comment: Oh dear, apologies to the OP for my ignorant comment. Thanks for pointing out my error @TedShifrin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**: If $\omega$ is a volume element on $T(M)$, then show that because $T$ is an isometry ("norm-preserving") it will follow that $T^*\omega$ is a volume element on $M$. Recall that a $k$-form $\eta$ on the oriented $k$-dimensional submanifold $M$ is a volume element precisely when $\eta_x(v_1,\dots,v_k) = 1$ whenever $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is an oriented orthonormal basis for the tangent space $M_x$.

Comment: I have some "naive sketch": $T$ preserves norms iff it preserves inner products. So $v_1,\dots,v_m$ is an orthonormal basis iff $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_m)$ is. Now by definition $(T^\ast\omega)(p)(v_1,\dots,v_m)=\omega(T(p))(T(v_1),\dots,T(v_m))=1$ because $\omega$ is the volume element. But I don't understand what $m$ should be, and bases for what spaces I should consider. If $\omega$ is the volume element on $T(M)$, then I should consider bases for tangent spaces for $T(M)$, but I don't know whether it's a manifold.

Comment: First, $m=k$. Second, yes, $T(M)$ is a manifold, because $T$, being a linear isomorphism, maps $M$ diffeomorphically to $T(M)$.

Comment: So, $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is an orthonormal basis for $T_pM$ iff $T(v_1),\dots,T(v_k)$ is an orthonormal basis for $T_{T(p)}T(M)$, and I guess my argument in the previous comment shows that $T^\ast \omega$ is the volume element on $M$ if $\omega$ is the volume element on $T(M)$. And then I believe I should apply the change of variables theorem to get $$\int_{T(M)}\omega=\int_M T^\ast\omega.$$ Is that correct? If yes, the only concerns I have are these: the above formula requires that $T$ be an orientation preserving - is it? Second, $T(M)$ should be orientable, which isn't obvious to me.

Comment: T(M) is orientable if and only if $M$ is. Prove it!

Comment: Thank you, I can try to prove it, but what about $T$ being orientation preserving? Do I need to say/prove anything about it to make the proof complete?

Comment: Well, whether $T$ is orientation-preserving or not, you'll get the right answer with absolute values, which Spivak does discuss. Note that if $M$ is connected, $T|_M$ is either everywhere orientation-preserving or orientation-reversing.